# How to create a multipart request with custom json data in request?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I want to create a multipart request with custom json data in request.

The JSON Request should be like this.

```
{
"name": {
    "fName": "fName",
    "lName": "lName"
},
"age": "age",
"gender": "gender",
"otherDetails": {
    "otherDetails1": "otherDetails1",
    "otherDetails2": otherDetails2
}
}
```

How to add this kind of JSON in multipart request with any file in the request?

Comment: What you showed is not a "JSON request". It's just some JSON. Where is the "multipart request"?

Comment: @matt How do send this kind of data with multipart request?

Comment: Do you know how to structure a multipart request at all?